# Tool / log location for subdomain settings on a Plesk server

Tags: centos

I'm trying to configure a new domain in Plesk 9 on our dedicated server, but for some reason the subdomain webmail isn't loading, and a traceroute does not resolve. I tried making another subdomain, test, which also fails to resolve.

The domain name is lsbc.co

I'm not really sure where to start is the main issue. As far as I know there is know subdomain equivalent to intodns.com. And Google isn't helping discover where the settings for subdomains are stored in this situation.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a DNS issue (if it doesn't resolve, the server isn't playing a part). Go to [kloth.net](http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php) and type in your domain name (without any subdomains) and select NS (nameserver) under the Query section. Hit lookup, and it will tell you where the DNS is stored for that domain.

You need to go to wherever that is and add subdomains (they make call them additional A records) for, at least, webmail.yourdomain.com. If you're lucky, they may even support adding wildcard DNS - add a subdomain of * and all subdomains not specifically mentioned will resolve to it.

To confirm it's a DNS issue, use kloth's A record lookup, or try to ping the subdomain - if it doesn't resolve (it should say PING domain.com (IP address) if it does), that's the issue. Don't worry too much if the PING times out as it could well be your hosting company blocking it.

EDIT: I just noticed you provided the domain in your question. I've checked and, as I thought, webmail.lsbc.co doesn't exist (** server can't find webmail.lsbc.co: NXDOMAIN). The DNS is hosted with 1and1 so you'll need to login to their control panel and add it there, if you have any issues they should be able to help.

Comment: Gah!! I've been messing about for the last two days trying to get to the bottom of this, my faulty assumption was of course that the domain name was actually pointing at our bloody nameservers.